# Troubleshooting a potentially broken camera

Tags: camera

How can I diagnose potential issues with Raspberry Pi camera?

I had [this camera](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073FGWK4C) hooked up to Raspberry Pi 2B v1.1. The Pi broke, and I hypothesize that the camera could have fried at the same time. I would like to get some clarity before purchasing another camera.

Often `v4l2-ctl -V` returns `Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.` and `raspistill` produces `failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)`. `vcgencmd get_camera` returns `supported=1 detected=0`

Rarely, it produces output with some camera specs, although it might be bogus the resolution is not 1080 vertical pixels. In these cases `raspistill` produces `failed to enable component: ENOSPC`. I read somewhere that ENOSPC message may indicate that someone *else* is *using* the camera, making me think that perhaps the camera is not fried?

Below are the details. I can produce more logs and outputs as needed.

- Running Raspbian 10 (buster), Linux 4.19.108+ armv6l.
- I got a Raspberry Pi Zero and a 15pin-22pin adapter cable so I can connect the camera.
- I followed the [troubleshooting checklist](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md), including:
- I updated raspberry pi,
- enabled camera in raspi-config,
- set aside 256MB RAM for GPU,
- added my user to the video group.
- Verified with multimeter that there is voltage (1.3V) on the camera (the cable is correctly seated)
- Unplugged any extra usb devices
- using power source with 2.5A output

Twice, by a fluke, `v4l2-ctl -V` produced a good output (but not 1080p resolution). I did not get a chance to run `vcgencmd get_camera` at that time.

```
ama@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
[sudo] password for ama:

ama@raspberrypi:~ $ v4l2-ctl -V
Format Video Capture:
Width/Height : 1024/768
Pixel Format : 'JPEG' (JFIF JPEG)
Field : None
Bytes per Line : 0
Size Image : 786432
Colorspace : JPEG
Transfer Function : Default (maps to sRGB)
YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default (maps to ITU-R 601)
Quantization : Default (maps to Full Range)
Flags :

ama@raspberrypi:~ $ raspistill -o test.jpg
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

Typically, however, it can't find the device

```
ama@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
[sudo] password for ama:

ama@raspberrypi:~ $ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=0

ama@raspberrypi:~ $ v4l2-ctl -V
Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.

ama@raspberrypi:~ $ raspistill -o test.jpg
mmal: Cannot read camera info, keeping the defaults for OV5647
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Camera is not detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly
```

By the way, `v4l2-ctl -V` detects three devices at `/dev/video10`, `/dev/video11` and `/dev/video12` - could this be a real camera, or are these virtual devices used by the driver?

Thank you for your tips!

Comment: Which OS +version? Can't see any reference to these details... And what is the output of `vcgencmd get_camera`? Please add details to the question.

Comment: Re extra v4l2 devices: they are normal with current driver, see https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=62364&p=1527503#p1527508

Comment: Good catch, I updated the post. Thanks for sharing re extra devices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with one of this cameras and a raspberry pi zero. Try to dismount the IR-Diodes - they have a high power demand and my guess is the CSI of the zero can´t deliver enough power - probably because of the smaller dimensions of the port and conductive tracks.

Comment: This is it! The camera worked after removing the extra IR LEDs.
I will try to find out their specs and power them from GPIO. Do you happen to know what's the preferred voltage for these?